# Downgrading from ZFC with universes to ZFC

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Is the following correct?

- If something is provable for small sets in ZFC with Axiom of Universes ("For any set x, there exists a universe U such that x∈U.") then it is provable for any sets in ZFC (without Axiom of Universes).

I want to work in ZFC with Axiom of Universes, but I wish my results be downgradable to plain ZFC. Help?

Comment: Can you please define "small set" in ZFC?

Comment: Have you seen the following MO question? It deals exactly with this topic

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12804/large-cardinal-axioms-and-grothendieck-universes

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24552/what-interesting-nontrivial-results-in-algebraic-geometry-require-the-existence-o/28913#28913

Comment: @goldstern - small set in ZFC+U is an element of U (and perhaps one isomorphic to an element of U, depending on one's proclivities)

Comment: @david roberts: I thought the question was not about "ZFC plus one additional constant (or predicate) U", but about an additional axiom postulating many universes. If every x is in some universe, which x should be called "small"?  Perhaps those in the smallest universe?

Comment: @goldstern: Fix some universe and call "small" its members.

Comment: @goldstern, I should have said $U$-small. Then you can talk about relative smallness of elements of a pair of universes, $U \in U'$, say.

Comment: Try Feferman set theory as an alternative: http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/feferman_set_theory.html

Comment: The main idea of Feferman set theory is what I describe in my answer below, except that he has one universe, and the theory I describe extends this to having a proper class tower of such universes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No can do.  ZFC+AU proves con(ZFC), ZFC doesn't.

Comment: What is "con"? Consistency?

Comment: yes  (char min)

Comment: As I understand, consistency of ZFC is a statement about small (even finite) sets and thus this gives a counter-example to my claim that we can move statements about small sets from ZFC+AU to ZFC. Right?

Comment: Porton, Yes, that is right. Con(ZFC) is an assertion of arithmetic that is provable in ZFC+AU, but not in ZFC, if ZFC is consistent.

Answer (score 12):

If you want a universe-like theory that is conservative over ZFC, that is, which proves no additional facts about sets that ZFC cannot prove alone, then the thing to do is to work in the following theory, which is also described in the [answers to this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24552/what-interesting-nontrivial-results-in-algebraic-geometry-require-the-existence-o/28913#28913).

The theory consists of ZFC plus the assertion that there is a hierarchy of universe-like sets, namely, $V_\theta$ for all $\theta\in C$, a closed unbounded proper class of cardinals, and furthermore that truth in these $V_\theta$ cohere with each other and with the full set-theoretic universe $V$, so that they form an elementary chain. Specifically, the theory has ZFC, the assertion that $C$, a new class predicate, is a closed unbounded proper class of cardinals, and the scheme asserting that $V_\theta$ is an elementary substructure of $V$ for every $\theta\in C$, namely, the scheme expressing of each formula $\varphi$ in the language of set theory that

- $\forall x\ \forall\theta\in C\text{ above the rank of }x \ (\varphi(x)\iff V_\theta\models\varphi[x])$.

It follows from this theory that the models $V_\theta$ for $\theta\in C$ form an elementary chain, all agreeing with each other and with the full set-theoretic background universe on what is true as you ascend to higher models. It follows that every $\theta$ in $C$ will be a strong limit cardinal, a beth fixed point and so on, and so these cardinal exhibit very strong closure properties. In particular, I could have written $H_\theta$ instead of $V_\theta$---these are essentially the $\theta$-small universes, the collection of sets of hereditary size less than $\theta$. The only difference between these $V_\theta$ and an actual Grothendieck universe is that in this theory, you may not assume that $\theta$ is regular. But otherwise, they function just like universes in many ways, and indeed, every $V_\theta$ for $\theta\in C$ is a model of ZFC. Because of the coherence in the theories, these weak universes can be more useful than Grothendieck universes for certain purposes. For example, any statement true about an object in the full background universe will also be true about that object in every weak universe $V_\theta$ for $\theta\in C$ in which it resides. Thus, it one takes care, one can use the $V_\theta$ much like Grothendieck universes, and this was the point of my linked answer above (as well as Andreas's).

Meanwhile, the theory is conservative over ZFC, since in fact every model of ZFC can be elementary embedded into (a reduct of) a model of this theory. This can be proved by a simple compactness argument, using the reflection theory. If $M\models ZFC$, then add constants for every element of $M$, add the full elementary diagram of $M$, add a new predicate symbol for $C$ and all the axioms of the new theory. Every finite subtheory of this theory is consistent, by the reflection theorem, and so we get a model of the new theory, which elementary embeds $M$ since it satisfies the elementary diagram of $M$.

(Although it seems counterintuitive at first to some set-theorists, this theory does not prove Con(ZFC), if ZFC is consistent, even though it asserts in a sense that $V_\theta$ is elementary in $V$ for all $\theta\in C$ and hence that $V_\theta$ is a model of ZFC. The explanation is that the theory only makes the assertion that $V_\theta$ is elementary in $V$ as a scheme, and not as a single assertion (which is not expressible anyway by Tarski's theorem), and thus the theory does not actually prove that $V_\theta\models ZFC$ for $\theta\in C$, even though they do model ZFC, since the theory only proves every finite instance of this, rather than the universal assertion that every axiom of ZFC is satisfied in every $V_\theta$.)

Comment: Does this theory have any wellfounded models?

Comment: If $\delta$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then by a Lowenheim-Skolem argument you can find a club $C\subset\delta$ with $V_\theta$ elementary in $C_\delta$ for $\theta\in C$, and so $\langle V_\delta,{\in},C\rangle$ is a model of the theory. 

Comment: In the displayed formulation of the reflection schema, $\theta$ should be big enough so that `$x\in V_\theta$`.

Comment: Yes, I have edited.

Comment: The theory described by Joel has the curious feature that it provides a definition of " $\phi$ is true in $(V, \in)$ for *standard* sentences of set theory [as opposed to those with nonstandard length] with via "$\phi$ holds on a TAIL of the structures of the form $V_{\alpha}$', where $\alpha\in C$". This does not contradict Tarski's theorem on undefinability of truth since $\phi$ is in the language using only $\in$, and is not allowed to mention $C$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I suppose that if one wanted to handle $\varphi$ in the language with $C$, then you could do the same trick again, having a club $D$ of $\theta$ for which $V_\theta$ reflect truth of $\langle V,\in,C\rangle$, and so on, iterating transfinitely!

Comment: Joel: one more aspect of the theory you described is that it is  conservative over $ZFC$ if you further add instances of replacement using formulas that mention $C$ to the theory.

Comment: Yes, the same compactness proof gives this, and I suppose that one could even have GBC, plus $C$ is a GBC class. 

Comment: Joel: That' right. One last point: Sol Feferman used a similar theory to yours to implement parts of category theory, see, e.g., Mike Shulman's 2008 paper *Set Theory for Category Theory* [arXiv: 0810.1279].

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my comment above (to the question), where David also links to Mike's paper, and Andreas says this also in his answer on the question to which I linked. I'm not quite clear on whether Feferman has just one $V_\theta\prec V$, or whether he has a proper class of them, but the idea is essentially the same. My student George Leibman made essential use of this theory in his work on versions of the Maximality Principle. 

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for the further clarification; Feferman's system uses a class of reflecting cardinals, by the way. Now that you mention it, I also remember seeing them in Leibman's paper.